# how to store multiple dynamic edittext value in android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have multiple dynamic **editTextBox**. I want to know how can I store all its edit textbox value?
what should I write in all edit box that should be I want a store on button click event.
My code is below:

```
for(i = 0 ;i < 6; i++) {
   TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
   TableRow tr1 = new TableRow(this);

   TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
   editText1 = new EditText(this);      
   editText1.setWidth(300);
   tr.addView(tv1);
   tbl.addView(tr);

   tr1.addView(editText1);
   tbl.addView(tr1);
}
```

Comment: Take Array in your code...
and using array u can store and get value back....
String array_name[i]

Comment: do you want to get editText1 value later? what do you mean by "store"?

Comment: @MustafaGüven i want get editText value store on click event

Comment: Than u can store value in Preference or SQLite Database.....

Comment: @MiteshTechMe ok but that all edittext value how can i get value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code.

```
EditText[] editText1 = new EditText[6];

for(i = 0 ;i < 6; i++) {
   TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
   TableRow tr1 = new TableRow(this);

   TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
   editText1[i] = new EditText(this);      
   editText1[i].setWidth(300);
   tr.addView(tv1);
   tbl.addView(tr);

   tr1.addView(editText1[i]);
   tbl.addView(tr1);
}

public void onClick(View v)
{
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
        Log.i("----value of EditText:"+i,"."+editText1[i].getText().toString());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

A direct answer to your question would be:

- remember your textviews when you create them (add them to an [`ArrayList`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html) for example)
- the onPause() method of your activity is the place to retain any information you want available later (android framework can finish() your activity anytime when it's paused).
- in an overrided onPause() method, cycle through your `ArrayList<TextView>`, retrieve each TextView content and store them for later use. (If you have a fixed number of TextViews, you may consider using [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref), but take a look at the remainder of this article to see if something better suits your needs.
- You can then use onCreate() or onResume() method to repopulate your TextViews before your application shows up.

An indirect, possibly better, answer would be to separate data from UI by using a data management class that would handle saving restoring and modifying your data and a customized [`Adapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html) which would be responsible of filling the TextViews. This way you can easily change the later to address different widgets.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote these codes without using editor, check it before using

```
String sValues="";
        for (int i = 0; i < tbl.getChildCount(); i++) {
            TableRow row =  (TableRow)tbl.getChildAt(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < row.getChildCount(); j++) {
                if(row.getChildAt(j) instanceof EditText){
                    EditText editText1 = (EditText)row.getChildAt(j);
                    sValues += editText1.getText().toString();
                }
            }
        }
```